# Utorrent Fails to Load all my torrent files

Tags: windows, utorrent

This morning I fired up my UT but none of my torrent files get loaded in UT. Can somebody help?

Things I tried:

- Torrent Files Storage location working fine.
- I also backed up my Utorrent Profile uninstall UT and reinstalled but again it does not seem to solve the issue.
- Utorrent stats are working fine though.
- I confirm all my HDD are working fine. Links to Images are below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- My Utorrent Version: 2.2.1
- Number of Torrents: 892 Added but not all of them are seeding
- Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate X86

Comment: Putting unnecessary formatting on everything doesn't make the question more readable nor it doesn't make us more willing to help. Please use the formatting reasonably.

Comment: Regardnig your issue, maybe it doesn't load because you don't have any torrents, as seen on the first screenshot?

Comment: I have 892 torrents which are stored in the I:\Torrent Files folder only today utorrent does not load any of them. Yesterday everything was fine.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you forgot to restore the profile backup. uTorrent actually stores torrent information in the profile files.

Comment: I restored my profile backup but the issue persists.